# Creating C# windows service that is called by en event in the browser

Tags: c#, c++, dll, windows-services

I am a java developer and very new to C# and C++. I am trying to create a windows service in c# that another web application will call to close one of the projects in c++. I've created a dll file in c++ with a method to close the application.

I created a web service as specified in http://www.cjvandyk.com/blog/Articles/How-do-I--Create-a-Windows-Service-application-using-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx. However, I am not sure how to call this service from the web application.

Can someone advise me or refer me to some place where I can learn how to do this?

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://arcanecode.com/2007/05/30/windows-services-in-c-sending-commands-to-your-windows-service-part-7/) can help?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to go Windows service route. Your web application should be able to do everything on the server side.

If you have to use Windows service, you will need to expose some sort of service; e.g. wcf net.tcp service to accept calls for closing your app.

I would suggest you revisit your solution of using windows service.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to all this so I did not really understand this.I am actually trying to modify code for safe exam browser which is an application on client side that opens everything in new window and disables various commands. It interacts with web application to get the exam. I want the new window to close when user submits the exam. For this purpose, I am trying to implement this we service.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a software utility Application as Service by Eltima company. It lainchibg any application a s a service and offers different options. So If I've understood you right - it will help you.

http://download.cnet.com/Application-As-Service/3000-2094_4-10338474.html?tag=mncol;9